# pigpio.start() error

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pigpio

Why am always getting this error when calling `pigpio.start()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/aa.py", line 9, in <module>
    pigpio.start()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start'
```

After installing pigpio.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pigpio.start() was deprecated (removed and replaced) years ago.

pigpio now allows multiple Pis to be controlled from one script.

You should now be using the following style.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi() # connect to Pi

if not pi.connected:
   exit()

pi.write(4, 1) # set GPIO 4 high

level = pi.read(7) # read GPIO 7

pi.stop() # disconnect from Pi
```

See pigpio [Python examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python%20code).